# flutter, two different textfields have the same value

Tags: flutter

I'm making a signup and a login page on flutter.
Because I knew I would use multiple textfields I made a single widget function to create one on demand. like this:

```
  Widget buildInput({bool obscureText, icon, labelText, Function change}) {
Color borderCo = HexColor('#88d5cb');

return Container(
  padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 35, left: 20, right: 20),
  child: Column(
    children: <Widget>[
      TextField(
        onChanged: change,
        obscureText: obscureText,
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          prefixIcon: Icon(icon),
            border: UnderlineInputBorder(
                borderSide: BorderSide(color: borderCo)),
            focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey)),
            enabledBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                borderSide: BorderSide(color: borderCo)),
            labelText: labelText,
            labelStyle: TextStyle(
              fontFamily: 'Arial',
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              color: Colors.grey,
            )
        ),
      )
    ],
  )
);
```

So everytime I need an input I just call it like this

```
buildInput(
        obscureText: false, 
        icon: Icons.mail, 
        labelText:'EMAIL', 
        change: (login) => setState(() => _loginEmail = login)
      ),
```

the problem is that I have one screen with two buttons, one for login and one for signup while the login button is chosen on default and the login widget is displayed as default.
if a user wants to signup he clicks the correct button and im rendering the other widget function I made for signup.
This is the loginWidget function:

```
Widget loginWidget(size) {
return Container(
  child: Column(
    children: <Widget>[
      buildInput(
        obscureText: false, 
        icon: Icons.mail, 
        labelText:'EMAIL', 
        change: (login) => setState(() => _loginEmail = login)
      ),
      buildInput(
        obscureText:true, 
        icon:Icons.lock, 
        labelText:'PASSWORD',
        change: (login) => setState(() => _loginPassword = login)
      ),
      SizedBox(height: 15,),
      SizedBox(
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.9,
        child: RaisedButton(
          disabledColor: Colors.grey[300],
          elevation: 8,
          child: Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10),
            child: Text(
              'LOGIN',
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, color: HexColor('#88d5cb')),
            ),
          ),
          color: Colors.white,
          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
            side: BorderSide(color: HexColor('#88d5cb')),
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
          ),
          onPressed: (EmailValidator.validate(_loginEmail) && _loginPassword.length >= 6) ?() async {
              try {
                Dialogs.showLoadingSpinner(context);
                bool isLoggedIn = await HttpServices.login(emailPass: { 
                  'email': _loginEmail, 
                  'password': _loginPassword 
                });

                if(isLoggedIn) { 
                  Dialogs.hideLoadingSpinner(context);
                  Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(
                    MaterialPageRoute(
                      builder: (BuildContext context) => CollabityHome()
                    )
                  );
                } else {
                  Dialogs.hideLoadingSpinner(context);
                  // Dialogs.showAlert(context, 'Email or password incorrect, try again.');
                  setState(() {
                    err = "The email or password you've entered doesn't match any account.";
                  });
                  print(err);
                }
              } catch(ex) {
                print('login ex: $ex');
              }
            }
            :
            null
        )
      ),
    ],
  )
);
```

}

My big problem is that when I type something for example in the email input of the login, but then I click the signup button to see the signup widget function, the inputs of the signup have the value of the inputs of the login who match their appearent location on the screen.

this is how I switch between the widgets I built for login and signup

```
swap? loginWidget(size) : signupWidget(size),
```

where the buttons change the boolean value of swap with setstate().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you create a `TextEditingController` for each of the inputs so that it can be passed in as an argument in your `buildInput()` function. This way it is easier to handle the values without confusion.

Comment: for each one, and is that the most elegant way? I very much appreciate that, ill try that right now.

Comment: Yes. It is the best way to ensure that you don't confuse the values of the signup inputs from those on the sign in inputs.

Comment: Glad I could help. It would help if you marked the answer as the accepted one :)